# How can I add the sandbox attribute to all iframes on my website using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

I need to globally add the sandbox attribute to all iframes on my website. Please and thank you.
Not sure where to start. It just needs to be sandbox it doesnt need to equal to anything. We are trying to update the security of the website overall.

Would this work?

```
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var frame of frames) {
    frame.setAttribute("sandbox");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example set sandbox with value in attribute

```js
var frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var frame of frames) {
    frame.setAttribute("sandbox", "allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-presentation allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-forms");
}
```

```html
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
<iframe></iframe>
```